# How to restrict the domain of a VehicleVar with disjunction for reload nodes?

Tags: or-tools

I would like to restrict the domain of a vehicle var for non-depot nodes as well as reload nodes. Also, reloading is optional. For example, suppose I have 8 nodes and 2 vehicles such that,

Vehicle 1: Capacity (3)

Vehicle 2: Capacity (4)

0 -> depot (All vehicles start and end here)

1 -> reload (Allowed vehicle -> {1,2})

2 -> reload (Allowed vehicle -> {1,2})

3 -> drop point (demand = 1) (Allowed vehicle -> 1)

4 -> drop point (demand = 1) (Allowed vehicle -> 1)

5 -> drop point (demand = 2) (Allowed vehicle -> 1)

6 -> drop point (demand = 1) (Allowed vehicle -> 2)

7 -> drop point (demand = 2) (Allowed vehicle -> 2)

Expected visiting sequence:

Vehicle 1 -> [0,3,4,1,5,0]

Vehicle 2 -> [0,6,7,0]

The way I tried to achieve this:

Without disjunction for the reload nodes (1st). (Edited)

```
#[routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NodeToIndex(i)], 0)
#for i in data['reloadNodes']]  # without penalty
```

Added restriction

```
for node_i in range(routing.nodes()):
  index_i = manager.NodeToIndex(node_i)  # internal index
  if node_i is depot_node: continue # Leave depot node
  allowed_vehicles = list(data['vehiclesAllowed'][node_i]) # Vehicles allowed to visit `node_i`
  if node_i in data['reloadNodes']:
     allowed_vehicles.insert(0, -1) # because reload nodes are optional.
  routing.VehicleVar(index_i).SetValues(allowed_vehicles)
```

But this way I got a result in which all reload nodes were visited (In this case vehicle 2 visited reload node 2 just before its last depot node, like this [0,6,7,2,0]). I have tried with more reload nodes but got the same behavior every time.

And this was fine because disjunctions were not there, therefore every node was visited. (Edited)

Then I tried with disjunction (uncommented the code snippet of point `1st` )

And after this change, I got no result after 50 sec run time with the status `ROUTING_FAIL_TIMEOUT`

Note: There was no restriction on trip max_time and max_length while trying this.

Please help me with this, I have the feeling that I have done something wrong with the disjunctions :)

Comment: I would like to mention when I adjust the demand (in the mentioned case demand of `node 5` to `1`) such that there is no need to reload the vehicle, it works fine and the solver returns the solution without the reload nodes in the visiting sequence of vehicles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the index of the vehicle var of `node_i` is not `node_i`, it is `index_manager.NodeToIndex(node_i)`.

The rest of the code seems to be correct.

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing this out, and I also realized that the code snippet to add disjunction was commented when I tried this, my apologies, I have made some changes in the post accordingly.

Comment: I got no solution when tried with disjunction and `-1` in the allowed vehicle list for the reload nodes after 50 sec of runtime. I don't know why this is happening, also I don't have an aggressive constraint for trip maximum time and distance.